# I have two questions regarding C#

Tags: c#

In my SubmitButton_Click method, I'm trying to add code to increase the score by 20 points for every correct answer. But for some reason its not adding 20 points each time I answer the question correctly it says 0. My other question is when my two random variables change when I click new and I type in the right answer it marks it as incorrect. Am I messing up somewhere regarding these two problems?

Here is my code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Lab4
{
    public partial class Lab4 : Form
    {
        public Lab4()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            score = 0;

        }

        private int score = 0;
        private int product = 0;
        private int answer = 0;


        private void SubmitButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            try
            {
                answer = int.Parse(AnswerTextBox.Text);
                if(Convert.ToInt32(AnswerTextBox.Text)==product)

                {

                    score=score+20;
                    MessageBox.Show("Correct!");                   
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Sorry, your answer is incorrect!");
                }

            }
            catch
            {
                MessageBox.Show("There was an error processing your answer!");
            }

        }



        private void NewButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
             Random rnd = new Random();
            int i, var1, var2, product;
            var1 = rnd.Next(1,9);
            var2 = rnd.Next(1,9);
            PromptLabel.Text = ("WHAT IS " + var1 +" . " + var2 + "?");
            product = var1 * var2;
            for (i = 10; i >= 1; i--)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("You have " + i + " sec(s) left!");
                TimeLabel.Text = ("Time: " + i + " sec(s)");

            }
        }

        private void ScoreLabel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void AnswerTextBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi and welcome. SO is better suited to helping you solve more specific problems. It is harder for the community to answer general questions like "why is my code not working?" Can I suggest you add some debug output to figure out what is going wrong. Or make your question more specific... all the best!

Comment: Did you try to debug? I am quite sure you will find the problem with the debugger. Why in SubmitButton_Click method you parse the value of the text box in the variable and on the next row you doing it again and the result is compared to product? Why you wouldn't use the variable?

Answer (score 1):

First problem is that you have declared a local variable inside method with same name as field in your form class. They are both named `product`. so the local variable is hiding the field and therefore no value is assigned to `product` in your class. so you have to remove local one or you have to use `this` keyword to tell the compiler to use the field inside the class.

You dont have to declare `product` here because you dont need it.

```
int i, var1, var2; //product; dont declare local variable. instead use the field which is already available
var1 = rnd.Next(1,9);
var2 = rnd.Next(1,9);
PromptLabel.Text = ("WHAT IS " + var1 +" . " + var2 + "?");
product = var1 * var2; // this.product = var1 * var2;
```

Another problem i see is the timer. your timer inside loop almost finishes instantly. because you dont wait for a second to countdown timer.

```
for (i = 10; i >= 1; i--)
{
    MessageBox.Show("You have " + i + " sec(s) left!");
    TimeLabel.Text = ("Time: " + i + " sec(s)");
    await Task.Delay(1000); // wait 1 second
}
```

for this you have to change signature of your method to async.

```
private async void NewButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
```

This maybe considered a poor design to do a count down timer. so i highly suggest you take a look at here to know how to correctly create count down timer.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492144.aspx

Answer (score 0):

change this line

`int i, var1, var2, product;`

to

```
int i, var1, var2;
```

it should solve the problem

Comment: why would removing `product` from the variable declarations fix an issue with the `score`?

Comment: @Claies because it is hiding the field `product`.

Comment: That wasn't clear from the body of your answer; if you update the answer I can remove the down vote.